# Click checkbox only if already checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, casperjs

I want to click on a checkbox only if it is already checked.

The following code doesn't seem to work:

```
if(this.test.assert(this.evaluate(function () {return document.getElementById('myID').checked;}))) 
{           
    this.click('#myID');     
}
```

What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test.assert*` functions are there for asserting a certain condition. Remove it because you want to branch the execution. Otherwise is your code correct.

```
test.assertExists("#myID");
// this function will not be executed if #myID wasn't there
var id = 'myID';
if(this.evaluate(function (pageCtxId) {return document.getElementById(pageCtxId).checked;}, id))
{           
    this.click('#'+id);     
}
```

Comment: I think there is still something I don't understand about `test.assert`. In what kind of situation do you use this function? is `test.assert` like an "if" condition except that you can only output a string?

Comment: `test.assert*` is there for when you want to execute some code that needs to be in a certain condition. When the condition (can also be done with `if`) is not true then `test.assert*` will fail and stop the execution of the current function. In the above case `#myID` should exist before you check its property.

Comment: I have a problem when I try to put this code inside a function: `function checkBox(id) {
 if(this.evaluate(function () {return document.getElementById(id).checked;})) {this.echo('#' + id + ' checkbox already checked');}
}` and try to call this function like that: `checkBox.call(this,'myId');` It looks like the if condition returns always false. I think it's a problem of format on the input argument `id` but I don't see which one. When I replace `id` by the string directly it works.

Comment: The function inside [`casper.evaluate`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) runs in the page context. Because of this, you cannot access variables defined somewhere else. You have to pass the specific variable to the `evaluate` call. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do it that way :

```
casper.waitFor(function checked() {
    return this.evaluate(function() {
        return document.getElementById('myID').checked === true;
    });
}, function then() {
    this.click('#myID');
});
```